# Как в GULP исключить папку из обработки

Tags: gulp

Нужно чтоб в папке с картинками папка **sprite** не переносилась в проект,
Пробовал 2 варианта

```
gulp.task('img', function () {
return gulp.src(['app/images/**/*','!app/images/sprite'])
.pipe(cache(imagemin({
    interlaced: true,
    progressive: true,
    optimizationLevel: 4,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    use: [pngquant()]
})))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

не помогло.
Потом пробовал через **gulp-ignore**

```
gulp.task('img', function () {
return gulp.src(['app/images/**/*','!app/images/sprite'])
.pipe(cache(imagemin({
    interlaced: true,
    progressive: true,
    optimizationLevel: 4,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    use: [pngquant()]
})))
.pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(ignoreSprite))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

**ignoreSprite** путь папки которую нужно игнорировать
Что не так, и как решить вопрос??

Comment: может быть вот так `'!app/images/sprite/'` или `'!app/images/sprite/**/*'` и пр. ?

Comment: Интересно то, что нужно и такой и такой вариант вписывать, спасибо, перенесите в ответы, поставлю как правильный

Comment: Еще имейте ввиду, что сначала указываете исключения, а только  потом включение. Варианта `!app/images/sprite/**/*` будет достаточно Т.е. `[ '!app/images/sprite/**/*', 'app/images/**/*']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь необходимо указывать чуть глубже:
`!app/images/sprite/`
`!app/images/sprite/**/*`
и пр.

P.S. Согласно замечанию [JaneDoe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/233430/jane-doe), сначала указываете исключения, а только потом включение. Варианта `!app/images/sprite/**/*` будет достаточно, т.е. `[ '!app/images/sprite/**/*', 'app/images/**/*']`